# How to use domProps in render function?

Tags: vue.js

here is a custom select component, it works, but I just can not understand some part of the code,

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0vrvh9c0/)

```
Vue.component("myselect", {
    props: ['option'],
    render: function (createElement) {
        var self = this    
        var items = []
        for (var i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            items.push(createElement('option', { attrs: { value: i } }, i))
        }

        return createElement('select', {

            domProps: { value: self.option.value }, // v-bind:value = this binds the default value
            on: {
                input: function (event) {
                    console.log(event.target.value)
                }
            }
        }, items)
    }
})
```

this sets the default value of select to `option.value`, is it `<select value='2'>`, but the html select tag uses `<option selected>`, looks like magic to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domProps` refers to [element *properties*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Properties), not *attributes*.

Think of it as something like this...

```js
document.getElementById('mySelect').value = 'Two'
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

When you set the `value` property on a select element, it selects the option with the corresponding value (at least in Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: Is this the right to work in vue? Accessing actual DOM directly!

Comment: My answer is an example using a comparison

Comment: Oops! Missed the line "Think of something like...".